# Stripping unknown keys when validating with Joi

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I'm using Joi to validate a JavaScript object in the server. The schema is like the following:

```
var schema = Joi.object().keys({
    displayName: Joi.string().required(),
    email: Joi.string().email(),
    enabled: Joi.boolean().default(false, "Default as disabled")
}).unknown(false);
```

The schema above will report an error if there is an unknown key in the object, which is expected, but what I want is to strip all the unknown silently, without an error.  Is it possible to be done?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use the `stripUnknown` option if you want to strip the unknown keys from the objects that you are validating.

cf options on https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#validatevalue-schema-options-callback

Comment: I saw this option, but reading the docs I though it would not work for what I need. But testing here, it worked.

Comment: Link is broken, see https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#validatevalue-schema-options-callback

Comment: This answer doesn't adequately explain how to use the `stripUnkwown` option.

Answer (score 9):

As in Version 14.3.4, there is a simple solution to this issue. Here is the code that solves the problem for you.

```js
// Sample data for testing.
const user = {
    fullname: "jayant malik",
    email: "demo@mail.com",
    password: "password111",
    username: "hello",
    name: "Hello"
};

// You define your schema here
const user_schema = joi
  .object({
    fullname: joi.string().min(4).max(30).trim(),
    email: joi.string().email().required().min(10).max(50).trim(),
    password: joi.string().min(6).max(20),
    username: joi.string().min(5).max(20).alphanum().trim()
  })
  .options({ stripUnknown: true });

// You validate the object here.
const result = user_schema.validate(user);

// Here is your final result with unknown keys trimmed from object.
console.log("Object with trimmed keys: ", result.value);
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the current way to include the strip unknown option:

```
const validated = customSchema.validate(objForValidation, { stripUnknown: true });
```

If you pass in an `objForValidation` that has a key which isn't defined in your `customSchema`, it will remove that entry before validating.

Answer (score 4):

```
const joi = require('joi');

joi.validate(object, schema, {stripUnknown:true}, callback);
```