# Remove unknown object properties using joi validation library

Tags: joi

I'm trying to use [joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) validation library and found in the [docs](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#validatevalue-schema-options-callback) that you can strip unknown properties from object and arrays using stripUnknow option. But this didn't work with me, here is sample code I'm testing on

```
const schema = Joi.object({
  firstName: Joi.string()
    .trim()
    .min(3)
    .required(),
  lastName: Joi.string()
    .trim()
    .min(3)
    .required()
});

let data = {
  firstName: "some name",
  test: "test value"
};

let result = Joi.validate(data, schema, {
  stripUnknown: true
});
console.log(util.inspect(result, {depth: 3}));
```

I'm expecting that the values returned from `Joi` to not include "test" but it is.

```
{ error: 
   { [ValidationError: child "lastName" fails because ["lastName" is required]]
     isJoi: true,
     name: 'ValidationError',
     details: 
      [ { message: '"lastName" is required',
          path: [Object],
          type: 'any.required',
          context: [Object] } ],
     _object: { firstName: 'some name', test: 'test value' },
     annotate: [Function] },
  value: { firstName: 'some name', test: 'test value' },
  then: [Function: then],
  catch: [Function: catch] }
```

I also checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31679374/striping-unknown-keys-when-validating-with-joi?rq=1) but it is not working as answered.

Comment: It's not stripping the unknown value because the validation didn't pass. The error is pretty clear, `lastName` is required and you've not included it. Allow the validation to pass and it will prune the unknown fields.

Comment: You are right, but this is strange behaviour, why it then returns the values, it should either don't return any value or return the valid once only, thanks.